# Realm Array and child relationships

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, realm

I am trying to make a List in relation to my realm array. I don't know if it is possible to take a hard coded realm array and give each string its own list. Currently I have my array in a table view and when a row is selected it segues to its own viewController. I am trying to get each selected row to contain its own list. Here's the code

Data Model 1

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class DateChange: Object {

    @objc dynamic var itemId : String = UUID().uuidString

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "itemId"
    }

    let dates = List<String>()
    let selection = List<Home>()

    convenience init(tag: String) {
        self.init()
    }
}
```

Data Model 2

```
class Home: Object {

  @objc dynamic var itemId : String = UUID().uuidString

 override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "itemId"
    }

    var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Home.self, property: "selection")
```

View Controller 1

```
class WeekOfViewController: NSViewController {

let post = DateChange(tag: "")

        post.dates.append("December 30th - January 5th")
        post.dates.append("January 13th - January 19th")

}

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 2

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let cell =  tableView.makeView(withIdentifier:
            NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "dateCell") , owner: self) as! NSTableCellView?
        cell?.textField?.stringValue = post.dates[row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "selectedDate", sender: self)

    }


    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Unwrap the segue's identifier.

        guard let identifier = segue.identifier else { return }
        // Make sure this is the segue we care about.

        if identifier == "selectedDate" {
            let secondVC = segue.destinationController as! ViewController2

            // Figure out which row was selected.
            if let selectedRow =  dateTableView?.selectedRow {
                secondVC.selectedDate = post.dates[selectedRow]

            }
```

View Controller 2

```
class ViewController2: NSViewController {

 @IBAction func saveData(_ sender: NSButton) {
        if let appendDate = selectedDate {
            do {
                 try realm?.write {
        let homeData = Home()
 homeData.done = false
        appendDate.dates.append()
            }
        } catch {
            print("There was an error saving")
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You initialise 'Home' object and you can return "itemId". But where is the string "itemId" set for Home object?

Comment: That was a typo sorry. It is in my project.

Comment: I don't understand how to use realm to make a list from hard coded arrays. I made my realm array, and appended each item. When I select an item it segues me to a new view Controller to create and save data to it's child element. I cant seem to make this work. please help

Comment: That's quite a bit of code but I think the core issue is the initial dataSource structure. You've got a static *post* object the dataSource for the tableView and maybe that's where the issue is. Generally you would have an array of objects as the datasource for the main tableview. When you tap a row, you get the object at that index and then get it's child properties to display in the second View controller. That could be details about the object or even another list. What you have could kinda work but it may be better to make your main dataSource an array of objects that hold child data.

Comment: Hey thanks Jay, How would I go about making an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can make multiple dimensional arrays.
Example:
1. Year object has a list of months
2. Month object has a list of days
3. Day object has a list of hours
4. etc, etc

When you app launches, you create a loop which initializes a Year, then initializes lots of months and appends them into the Year.Month_Array. Do the same for days_array in each month.

To save in Realm, call:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(Year)
}
```

Now you can read out you multi-level Realm object anytime you wish.

If my answer isn't clear, please let me know

Comment: yeah please if you could clarify how I would loop 'itemId' in my dataModel  to this array-  let post = DateChange(tag: "")

        post.dates.append("December 30th - January 5th")
        post.dates.append("January 13th - January 19th")

Comment: If my example, when you fetch the 'Year' object, it'll come out as a JSON object that you can easily loop.
1. Fetch a post from realm which has an itemId you want.
2. use a simple for-loop to loop through all de dates in that pos:
'for date in post.dates { ... your code ...}'

Is this clear? or didn't I understand you question correctly?

Comment: Maybe I asked the wrong question, I'm not sure that would have the desire effect I am looking for. I am trying to create a "linkingObject" when a row is selected. My post.dates are simply strings that populate a tableView. when a desired row is selected I want it to create a relationship to a Realm Link. Much Like a todo list app that consists of Categories and Items. This example simply has a categories table view that is hard coded with pre determined categories. When a category is selected it should segue to its child item list.

Answer (score 0):

The exact use case is a bit unclear but it seems that the app is a Master->Detail configuration where the master page contains a list of dates and then when a date is tapped, it segues to a detail page with further info.

Here's an example of code to handle the objects. You know how to populate a tableView with it's delegate methods so I'm omitting that part.

Suppose we want a list of events on the master page and then the activities of each event on the detail page. Start with two managed Realm objects; the event object which has a start and end date, the event title and the activities list within that event. Then there's the activity object.

```
class EventClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var start_date: Date?
    @objc dynamic var end_date: Date?
    @objc dynamic var event_title = ""
    let activities = List<ActivityClass>()
}

class ActivityClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
}
```

write an event with some activities to Realm

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyymmdd"

let e0 = EventClass()
e0.event_title = "Workshop"
e0.start_date = formatter.date(from: "20180113")
e0.end_date = formatter.date(from: "20180119")

let a0e0 = ActivityClass()
a0e0.title = "Some activity"
let a0e1 = ActivityClass()
a0e1.title = "Another activity"
let a0e2 = ActivityClass()
a0e2.title = "Activity continues"

e0.activities.append(a0e0)
e0.activities.append(a0e1)
e0.activities.append(a0e2)

// write event 0 (e0) to realm which will create the event and activities
```

We are assuming both the master and detail views have tableViews, so load the events into the master tableView dataSource which is a Realm results class - it behaves like an array.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var eventResults: Results<EventClass>? = nil
```

and then whenever it's time to populate the dataSource:

```
self.eventResults = realm.objects(EventClass.self)
```

and then the tableView delegate methods can get each row for display. It would look something like this on the master page

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let cell =  tableView.makeView(withIdentifier:
            NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "dateCell") , owner: self) as! NSTableCellView?
        //cell?.textField?.stringValue = post.dates[row]
        let event = self.eventResults[row]
        cell.textField?.stringValue = "Event: \(title) from: \(start) - \(end)"
        return cell
    }
```

so then the tableView would look something like this

```
Event: Workshop from: 2018-12-30 - 2018-01-05
Event: Workshop from: 2018-01-13 - 2018-01-19
etc
```

when a row is tapped, get that event object from the master tableView datasource, self.eventResults

```
let tappedEvent = self.eventResults[tappedRowIndex]
```

and then get the activity list

```
let activityList = tappedEvent.activities
```

that activityList can be passed via the segue (or 1000 other ways) to the detail viewController and it becomes the dataSource for the detail tableView. The detail page follows the same pattern except the dataSource is the activities.

Does that help?